# Valores de una lista en un Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

1.- Tengo un diccionario con claves y valores. Sin embargo los valores son un arreglo --> Clave : [Arreglo]

Después creeo un data frame a partir de este diccionario. Pero justamente el data frame me aparecen los valores como lista.

2.- Mi código:

```
def tipo_uno_fr():

    df_ti = pd.DataFrame([[clave_sis, dic_t1[clave_sis]] for clave_sis in dic_t1.keys()], columns=['ID_SISTEMA', 'ID_DATO'])

    return df_ti



tipo_uno_fr()
```

---

Mi salida:
[image: Salida_obtenida]

Lo que quisiera es el *ID_SISTEMAS* repetido por cada *ID_DATO*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede crear el dataframe con un *list comprehension* con 2 variables:

```py
import pandas as pd

def tipo_uno_fr():
    df_ti = pd.DataFrame([[sis, dat] for sis in dic_t1 for dat in dic_t1[sis]],
                         columns=['ID_SISTEMA', 'ID_DATO'])
    return df_ti

dic_t1 = {f'SIS_{sis:02}': [f'DAT_{dat:02}_SIS_{sis:02}' for dat in range(1, 4)]
          for sis in range(1, 5)}
print(dic_t1)
df = tipo_uno_fr()
print(df)
```

Resultado:

```
{'SIS_01': ['DAT_01_SIS_01', 'DAT_02_SIS_01', 'DAT_03_SIS_01'],
 'SIS_02': ['DAT_01_SIS_02', 'DAT_02_SIS_02', 'DAT_03_SIS_02'],
 'SIS_03': ['DAT_01_SIS_03', 'DAT_02_SIS_03', 'DAT_03_SIS_03'],
 'SIS_04': ['DAT_01_SIS_04', 'DAT_02_SIS_04', 'DAT_03_SIS_04']}

   ID_SISTEMA        ID_DATO
0      SIS_01  DAT_01_SIS_01
1      SIS_01  DAT_02_SIS_01
2      SIS_01  DAT_03_SIS_01
3      SIS_02  DAT_01_SIS_02
4      SIS_02  DAT_02_SIS_02
5      SIS_02  DAT_03_SIS_02
6      SIS_03  DAT_01_SIS_03
7      SIS_03  DAT_02_SIS_03
8      SIS_03  DAT_03_SIS_03
9      SIS_04  DAT_01_SIS_04
10     SIS_04  DAT_02_SIS_04
11     SIS_04  DAT_03_SIS_04
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, me funciono muy bien. Muchas gracias